# Парсинг даты из строки

Tags: javascript, дата, datetime

Как из такой строки можно извлечь дату?

```
  Tue Apr 02 2019 12:00:00 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)
```

И привести её к такому:

```
    2019-01-21T08:59:45.84345Z
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const d1 = new Date('Tue Apr 02 2019 12:00:00 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)');
console.log(d1.toISOString());
```

Answer (score 2):

Тот вывод, который Вы хотите получить - это формат [**ISO**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Дата будучи сконструированной от строки которую вы привели в вопрос сама получит правильный `timestamp`:

```js
let d = new Date('Tue Apr 02 2019 12:00:00 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)')
console.log(d.getTime())
console.log(d)
d = d.toISOString()
console.log(d)
```

метод [`.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) приводит дату в формат [ISO](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

---

К слову такой вывод, который у Вас на входе генерирует обычный [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString) у объекта `Date`

```js
console.log(new Date().toString())
```